# Splitting fields over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find a splitting fields over $\mathbb{Q}$ for:

i)$x^4+4=(x^2-2x+2)(x^2+2x+2)$ (both factors are irreducible). The roots: $x_1=1+i,\ x_2=-(1+i)$. So the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, which has deg 2 over Q.

ii)$x^6-8=(x^2-2)(x^4+2x^2+2)$. The roots: $x_1=1, \ x_2=-1$. 4 left so it will be $e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{6}}$. So the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(e^{\frac{2\pi i}{6}})$ And deg is also 2?

iii)$x^4+5x^2+6=(x-i)(x+i)(x-i\sqrt5)(x+i\sqrt5)$. So the splitting field will be $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt5,i)$ and deg 4?

Is that correct?

Comment: In (ii), $\sqrt{2}$ is in the splitting field of the polynomial but it is not in the stated field, $\Bbb Q(e^{\pi i / 3})$.

Comment: Yes, stupid mistake. So $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}})$ and deg 4?

Comment: I can't edited anymore. $\sqrt 2$ is in $e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}}$. So deg 2? How we to find normal closure. for example for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{3})$

Comment: For i and iii, where did you pull those factorizations from? They're not correct.

Comment: ...and for $2$, where did you pull those roots from? You're saying that $1^6-8=0$?

Comment: I was doing to much at time.  i) is correct. iii) should be $\sqrt2 $ and $\sqrt 3$. Sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For i) The roots are the powers of $\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{i \pi}{4}}$ and a splitting field is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{i \pi}{4}})$.

For ii) The roots are the powers of $\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{i \pi}{3}}$ and a splitting field is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{i \pi}{3}})$.

For iii)
$$x^4+5x^2+6=(x^2+2)(x^2+3)=(x-i\sqrt{2})(x+i\sqrt{2})(x-i\sqrt{3})(x+i\sqrt{3})$$ and a splitting field is $\mathbb Q(i\sqrt{2},i\sqrt{3})$

Comment: Yes, that I was have in mind. I wrote it wrong. Can you tell me, what's degree of that?

Comment: You should be able to find that using the orders of the elements generating the Galois groups.